# problem with linux-image-5.15.0-73-generic

Tags: apt

i try all the things , and no one works

first

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:obsproject/obs-studio
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install obs-studio
```

when i put this they give me the error `linux-image-5.15.0-73-generic`
then i try

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get remove linux-image-5.15.0-73-generic
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get install -f
```

with `sudo apt-get remove linux-image-5.15.0-73-generic` , appers to use apt --fix-broken install , i put it but this is the answer

```
Se encontraron errores al procesar:
 linux-image-5.15.0-73-generic
Proceso detenido por haber demasiados errores.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

PS: sorry for my english :(

Comment: I recently installed `linux-image-5.15.0-73-generic` with no issue whatsoever. Please include any error message you get in your question. Thanks. 

Comment: what a have to do ? i need for installa and app for the university , pls help me

Comment: Include the full output of the commands you tried in your question. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know why the text is like this

Comment: It appears you had an error with `linux-image-5.15.0-73-generic`. Try: `sudo apt install --reinstall linux-image-5.15.0-73-generic`.

Comment: Se encontraron errores al procesar:
 memtest86+
 linux-image-5.19.0-42-generic
 linux-image-5.15.0-73-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)